# How to check if radio button group is required

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, radio-group, required

I have a dynamic radio button group where the `required` attribute may not be specified on all inputs.

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="radio" id="option1" name="foo" value="First" >
    <input type="radio" id="option2" name="foo" value="Second" required>
    <input type="radio" id="option3" name="foo" value="Third">
    <input type="radio" id="option4" name="foo" value="Fourth">
</form>
```

Is there a way to check in JavaScript whether the radio button group is required without iterating through all inputs in the group?

I have looked at input element's `validity.missingValue` property which works when no radio button is selected but I have no solution for when the field is valid. Currently I have the following code, but it would be nice if there was some other property to use e.g. on the `HTMLInputElement` or `RadioNodeList`.

```js
function isRequired() {
    return Array.from(document.myform.foo).some(i => i.required)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that ?

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form'];

console.log( !!myForm.querySelector('input[name="foo"][required]') )  // true
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="First" >
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Second" required >
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Third" >
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Fourth" >
</form>
```

You can also add a "dirty wrapper":

```js
// define new getter property (dirty wrapper)
RadioNodeList.prototype.__defineGetter__( 'isRequired', function(){ return [...this].some(r=>r.required) });

const myForm = document.forms['my-form'];

console.log(  myForm.foo.isRequired ); // true
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="First">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Second" required>
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Third">
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Fourth">
</form>
```